# C# - Using a keyboard shortcut to quickly open picture files

Tags: image, key

I'm trying to figure out how to write code to quickly open a PNG file from within my little program. Here's the scenario:

- I have multiple picture files, say PNG's, in multiple folders (in the same root as the program).
- I want to be able to recall any of those pictures and display them quickly with as few keystrokes as possible, and hopefully no mouse needed.

Then, while the program is active, I want to be able to

1. Press a key to let the program know I want to load a new file, say "O";
2. Type the two-digit folder name, such as "LL", and
3. Type a two-digit filename, such as "05" (where the extension ".png" is assumed)
4. the program opens the /LL/05.png file and displays it full-screen

I have been able to make a "predetermined" picture display, and gotten a Open File Dialogue box to display, but not the direct method I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is not perfect and should need a lot of additional checks.
Anyway it's a starting point for your needs.
First of all set `KeyPreview = true` on your form.
Then use:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool reading = false;
    private byte dirSize = 2;
    private byte filesize = 2;
    private string keys = "";
    private const string defExt = ".png";
    private string exePath = 
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
        {
            reading = true;
            keys = "";
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        if (reading)
        {
            Char ch = (char)(e.KeyValue);
            if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch))
            {
                keys += ch;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (keys.Length == (dirSize + filesize))
            {
                string dir = Path.Combine(exePath, keys.Substring(0, dirSize));
                string filename = keys.Substring(dirSize, filesize) + defExt;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fullPath);
                reading = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Marco, I got pulled away on a different project, so I didnt get to try this yet. Planning on getting back to this in the morning. Thanks so much!

Comment: Marco, on the line:
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

I get this, "The name "Assembly" does not exist in the current context."

Everything else looks to be fine, although I haven't launched it yet until I get this message figured out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimS: hey, this is easy, you should solve yourself ;) You need to write `using System.Reflection;` at the beginning of your class :)

Comment: Thinking through this, I'd be just as happy Setting the current directory when the program opens...something like:

if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                // Set the current directory.
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory() = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

(I just haven't gotten that to work yet...) :-(

Comment: @TimS: first, your question is about something different, so you should close it (approving or not, upvoting or not); second: if you need to set directory where catching files, do `if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) exePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;` so you don't have to modify code I provided ;)

Comment: Man, I'm sorry - I'm too much of a newbie to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. So, I've written `using System.Reflection;` - That made Assembly work - THANKS!<br/>

Comment: Thanks for showing me the ropes on here. I get that that's a second question. <br/>

Comment: So, my program will run now, but the key combination "O" "LL"(directory name) "01"(png filename) doesn't make anything happen.  But, my TestSlide.png does work: `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("\\TestSlide.PNG");`

Comment: Did you set `KeyPreview = true` on your form? If something doesn't work properly you should use debugger to find it ;) Set a breakpoint inside `Form1_KeyDown` function and check what's wrong. Last: did you set `KeyDown` event of your form to _point_ to this function?

Comment: KeyPreview is set to true. Could we perhaps move this to chat, let me send you the code, and have you help me fix it? Is paying you for your time appropriate?... I feel like I am SO close, but my skill level is holding me back. :-)

Comment: zip your solution and send me by email (marco dot giacinti at gmail dot com): in some hour I find time to check and fix it :)

Comment: I sent you an email with the zipped solution attached. THANKS!

Comment: @TimS: as I told you on my previous comment, you forgot to set `KeyDown` event of `Viewer` form to `Viewer_KeyDown` procedure!!! Set it and everything works like a charm :)

Comment: That's where I'm having trouble - I've tried several different things and each has failed. Would you mind telling me how that line of code is supposed to look? THANKS!

Comment: @TimS: You can do it in GUI!! Select Viewer, then in properties tab switch to events, then on `KeyDown` combobox select `Viewer_KeyDown`. If you want to do it with code you should try `this.KeyDown += Viewer_KeyDown;`

Comment: AHHHH, I am SO sorry - now I get it! I had to set the KeyDown PROPERTY of the Viewer form in the Design view! So sorry, Marco - I'm a newbie, what can I say?... As usual, the fix is always simple once you know what it is... :-)